# Inconsistent spacing between bootstrap rows with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have following, a view in angular with a map and then, right below it, a list of superregions which I am getting from a controller repeating across the view. At this time, the superRegions are in two columns, which I want. However, you can see from the following picture that there is inconsistent padding in between them, which I definitely don't want. I've tried everything but cannot seem to mitigate the spacing. It's not a problem on the right column but on the left column it definitely is.

```
    <div class="modal-ui-view" ui-view="regionManagementModalView" ></div>
<div class="region-listing-info" id="region-listing-info">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="portlet col-md-6">
            //The map directive
        </div>
        <div class="portlet col-xs-6 col-md-6" ng-repeat="superRegion in superRegionCollection">
            //a list of superRegions with styling
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's driving me crazy and I must have tried eleven solutions. How can I keep consisting vertical spacing on the left column like the right column has?[image]

Comment: Why do you have two column sizes in `class="portlet col-xs-6 col-md-6"`?

Comment: That was left over from me trying something just now, but removing that gives me the exact same result.

Comment: OK. I think an example (Fiddle, Plnkr) would get you help faster :)

Comment: What is inside col-md-6 (i mean code)?

Comment: looks like a css issue, you need to use the browser's debug tools to inspect what is causing the space